# Rails Zeitwerk loads modules 'partial'? ie. my Module calls 'extend OtherModule', but the rest of the module in the file is ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

*Intro:*

I am migrating my application from Rails 3.2.x to Rails 7.0.4.2. I am much more far already, than I expected.

Although I am a zeitwerk noob, I like that approach - especially the "no require" part.

To be sure, that I do not have any `require`s I renamed all to `require3`, that only does something in rails 3 (I also have a `require7` for those cases where it is really needed).
In parallel I have a red line for those in console.

*The module:*

The module is `BotCheck` (yes, a capture) and is located as `bot_check.rb` in `lib`. Needed classes are in `lib/bot_check/.`.

The source of BotCheck is short. One extend and two methods (these are somehow 'global'). All the rest is behind in classes in `lib/bot_check/.`

```
# lib/bot_check.rb

module BotCheck
    extend Configurable

    configurable do
        global_attr etw_divider: 5
        global_attr etw_min_level: 0
    end
    
    # this for debugging …
    puts "loading ====================== module BotCheck".blue.on_yellow

    def self.bot_check_from_bot_id(id)
        …
    end

    def self.bot_check_level
        …
    end
    
    def bot_check_from_bot_id(id)
        BotCheck.bot_check_from_bot_id(id)
    end

    def bot_check_level
        BotCheck.bot_check_level
    end
end
```

All the needed modules and classes are like

```
#lib/bot_check/what_ever.rb

module BotCheck
    class WhatEver
        include BotCheck #only some classes 
        …
        …
    end
end
```

I ran this in the old world Rails 3 an all works as expected (even without a require!)

Running it with Rails 7 (zeitwerk), I got "`undefined method BotCheck.bot_check_level`" called from `BotCheck::TagHelper` (not a helper just a module that creates the tags), as if the module `BotCheck` it self was not loaded.

This is not possible, because `BotCheck.config` is here and also the logger line from `Configurable`. that `configurable` was called.

```
    Configurable: ++++++++++++++++++ extended(BotCheck)
```

The next try (after 2 hours not understanding anything) was to add the line above (puts "module loaded"

with rails3 I got:

```
Configurable: ++++++++++++++++++ extended(BotCheck)
loading ==================module BotCheck
```

with 7

```
Configurable: ++++++++++++++++++ extended(BotCheck)
"nope" something else
```

So I put a `require7 'bot_check'` (remember only for rails 7 not for 3 needed)  in application.rb

Now I have my two lines, and everything works.

*Conclusion*:

Zeitwerk finds the Module, lets me include the module, executes `extend` within the module, **but** does not load it.

Now I have questions, because I do not expect me to find a zeitwerk bug after a few days working with it.

- What is the idea behind this?
- How is the state of such a module called? "somehow"?
- What about the no require idea? Or:
- how to completely load a module without a require, if not even an include does the job?
- Where to put the require if no other solution?
- What about side effects? Methods of a module or class that includes such "somehow" loaded, get the included Methods after the module is fully loaded. I do not want to search errors because of that. I made this small check:

  module BotCheck
  class BotCheckController<SiteController
  include BotCheck

  ```
  def check
      puts "botcheck config: #{BotCheck.config}
      puts "11111111111111 #{self.respond_to?(:bot_check_from_bot_id)}"
      puts "22222222222222 #{BotCheck.respond_to?(:bot_check_from_bot_id)}"
      require7 "bot_check"
      puts "33333333333333 #{self.respond_to?(:bot_check_from_bot_id)}"
      puts "44444444444444 #{BotCheck.respond_to?(:bot_check_from_bot_id)}"
      …
  ```

with this output:

```
botcheck config: #<Configurable::BotCheckConfig:0x00007f5080c7c450>
11111111111111 false
22222222222222 false
Warning: Require for 7:'bot_check' in: /home/user/appl/lib/bot_check/bot_check_controller.rb:11:in `check'
Configurable: ++++++++++++++++++ extended(BotCheck) ((<- this is the 2nd time of extend logged))
loading ==========================================================================module BotCheck
33333333333333 true
44444444444444 true
```

**Edit based on comment:**

The module Configurable is loaded during initialization. So it is available in initializers. Like (for BotCheck): (please note the String!)

```
Configurable.setup("BotCheck") do |config|
    config.etw_divider=20
    config.etw_min_level=0
end
```

The module sits and waits for `extend Configurable` and only after this call it injects the config into the other module. (as far as I know, it's the same algorithm, that rails has know built in. Just without parameter checking)

The module it self does not know anything about the modules that are using it until `extend`

Comment: Let me understand a bit better the situation. First of all, no `require`s is not something new with Zeitwerk, the application should not issue `require` calls for autoloadable code in Rails 3 either, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#autoloading-and-require. Now, is `lib` in the autoload paths? Did you change when is `Configurable` loaded during the upgrade? Where is `Configurable` and how is it loaded?

Comment: lib is in autoload paths, no changes made. Configurable is (again back) in lib. I had it for test in myapp/gem_canditates and used auto_load_once, but because of troubles with rail 3 i put it back to lib.
The main interesting I put in edit part of my question.

Comment: @XavierNoria, thx you gave me the right direction to search! I had an stone old version of BotCheck in controllers, Configurable was not the reason, but helped me to find this one. After commenting out extend, i still got the logger line extended …

Answer (score 0):

1st thanks to Xavier Noria, his comment helped me to find the problem.

2nd, as I expected, it was my fault. Zeitwerk is clean!

I had a stone old zombie "bot_check.rb" in controllers, that only "extend Configurable" had.

After removing this, all works as designed / expected.

The question was **exactly** was going on, would need further investigation, but - I be true - two files same name, same module, but different content in different autoload-pathes …

Comment: Awesome. Yes, in general you cannot load two files with the same name at the same "level" in Ruby, unless you manually manage them. That is, if you `require "foo"` in pure Ruby, and there are two `foo.rb` in `$LOAD_PATH`, Ruby only loads the first one. Zeitwerk mimicks this, if you have two `bot_check.rb` in the root directories (in the same level/namespace), [the second one is ignored](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#shadowed-files).

Comment: @XavierNoria: Yes, this error gets into my top ten ever, because the file was only slumbering on the remote pre production linux server in controllers, localy in development I could no see it!